# Why am I getting a "min() arg is an empty sequence" error in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I was trying to solve this python problem for practice in which I have to find the sum of the minimum and maximum 4 integers out of the 5 in a list. My logic seems to be fine as it is working for the max array but I don't know why is it having a problem to work on the min array.

**CODE**

```py
arr=list(map(int, input().split()))

def miniMaxSum(arr):
    maxarr=arr
    minarr=arr
    minsum=0
    maxsum=0
    for i in range(4):
        maxsum+=max(maxarr)
        maxarr.remove(max(maxarr))
        minsum+=min(minarr)
        minarr.remove(min(minarr))
    print(minsum,maxsum)

miniMaxSum(arr)
```

**INPUT**

```
10 2 5 8 3
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT***

```
18 26
```

**But it gives me this error**

```
<ipython-input-1-2cb97cb38fd0> in miniMaxSum(arr)
      9         maxsum+=max(maxarr)
     10         maxarr.remove(max(maxarr))
---> 11         minsum+=min(minarr)
     12         minarr.remove(min(minarr))
     13     print(minsum,maxsum)

ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

Comment: Because `minarr` is empty.

Comment: More specifically, because minarr and maxarr are two names for the *same* list, so when you remove an item from one it is removed from the other too.

Comment: Okay okay, I didn't know that it was just getting referenced instead of being cloned. @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass an immutable object (list, for example) into a function, you actually pass it by reference. You can see this easily by printing out `minarr` before and after the removal:

```
def miniMaxSum(arr):
    maxarr=arr
    minarr=arr
    minsum=0
    maxsum=0
    for i in range(4):
        print(i)
        print(minarr)
        maxsum+=max(maxarr)
        maxarr.remove(max(maxarr))
        print(minarr)
        minsum+=min(minarr)
        minarr.remove(min(minarr))
    print(minsum,maxsum)
```

To fix this, you can create a copy of a list:

```
maxarr=arr.copy()
minarr=arr.copy()
```

Also... just a suggestion... it would be a lot easier if you calculate the sum `s` of the entire list. Then you can set

```
minsum = s - max(arr)
maxsum = s - min(arr)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the suggestion at the end! Didn't think of it.